Can you have a function that is differentiable, yet the jacobian matrix is not continuous?
Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ that is differentiable at $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We all know that this means that there exists a linear map $D_{f(x)} \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ such that $f(x+h)$ can be approximated by the affine linear map $f(x) + D_{f(x)}h$ for small values of h.
We also know that $D_{f(x)}$ (if it exists) has matrix representation $\partial f(x)$. I also know that if  $\partial f(x)$ is continuous on some open ball around $x$, then we know that $\partial f(x) = D_{f(x)}$.
My question is, is it possible to have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ Such that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and  $\partial f(x) = D_{f(x)}$ but $\partial f(x)$ is not continuous at $x$?
If possible can someone give an example? If not can someone prove it? My guess is that it is possible, it would just be some function whose derivative is not continuous but excited to see what everyone has to say.

How about the classic $f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \
0 & \mbox{if } x=0
\end{cases}$?

$f(x)=x^2 \cos ({1\over x})$ does the job : $f'(x)=\sin ({1\over x})+2x \cos ({1\over x})$ if $x=\not = 0$ and $f'(0)=0$. Note that $f'({1\over \pi/2+2n\pi})$ goes to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.
